# me sale este error An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: sql-server

Estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado que solo hace inserts pero antes tengo que ver si no existe ya, lo cual lo represento en este codigo

````
CREATE PROC nuevoEscaneo(@servidor Varchar(20), @momento VARCHAR) 
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @ser varchar(20) = @servidor
    if
    (select COUNT(*) from dbo.Servidores WHERE IP = @ser)
    begin
    print 'algo salio mal'
    end
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
    Insert into Servidores (IP) values (@servidor) 
    Insert into Escaneos(Servidor, Momento) values (@servidor, @momento);
    END
END ```
Alguien sabe mi error?
````

Comment: ¿Qué pretendes hacer con esto: `if(select COUNT(*) from dbo.Servidores WHERE IP = @ser)` Lo que te dice el mensaje de error es que no hay una comparación booleana ahí. Ese select te arrojará un número, no un booleano. Supongamos que quieres verificar que haya registros, entonces, deberías poner algo así: `if (select COUNT(*) from dbo.Servidores WHERE IP = @ser > 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
> condition is expected

Es decir, una expresión no lógica se está usando en el contexto dónde se esta esperando un valor lógico. El problema es:

```
if (select COUNT(*) from dbo.Servidores WHERE IP = @ser)
```

El `if` espera un valor lógico (True/False) pero el `select` retorna un valor numérico: la cantidad de filas. Imagino que el control que estarías intentando es verificar si la consulta no retorna filas, por lo que deberías hacer algo así:

```
if (select COUNT(*) from dbo.Servidores WHERE IP = @ser) = 0
```

O bien, podrías validar la consulta con el `EXISTS()`

```
if NOT EXISTS(select COUNT(*) from dbo.Servidores WHERE IP = @ser)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!, eso era!